Issues with y-axis offset in curve fitting for sinusoidal wave data
I am working on a curve-fitting optimization problem using sinusoidal wave data. I have around 16 cycles of almost identical sine wave data, but I am encountering an issue with the y-axis offset. The offset is always slightly off, and I am not sure what might be causing this discrepancy.
Here is a brief description of my data and approach:

Data: 16 cycles of sine wave data
Problem: The y-axis offset is    consistently incorrect
Goal: To    accurately fit the sine wave data and    correct the
y-axis offset

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you!
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
def sine_wave(t, A, phi_beta, phi_alpha, C):
   return A * np.sin(2 * np.pi * primary_frequency * t + phi_beta*t +phi_alpha) + C

initial_guess = [np.ptp(CH2) / 2, 800, 200, np.mean(CH2)]
params, _ = curve_fit(sine_wave, time, CH2, p0=initial_guess, maxfev=10000)

A, phi_beta,phi_alpha, C = params
fitted_CH2_with_primary_freq = sine_wave(time, average_amplitude, phi_beta, phi_alpha, C)

The output is below:


Your data ISN’T a sine wave. It just happens to be periodic. Which isn’t the same thing. If you take an FFT then you can probably write it as a modest combination of sine waves.

It's not obvious to me that you'd get a better fit if the C parameter were increased - in some places in the graph the red dotted line is too high, which means that increasing C would decrease the quality of the fit there. Can you post the data, as a reproducible example?

Are your x points equally spaced? If one area has more data points per second, that will effectively have more influence on the fit of the overall line.

The FFT is done; the primary_frequency = the highest number in the frequency domain. The x-axis data is equally spaced in time. I am not sure how to upload my data to make it reproducible. From the graph, I think the A and C changes could give a significantly better fit.

You can test that. Compute the residual using the C value from scipy and then increase it slightly and see if that improves the residual.

One way would be to run np.savetxt('time.txt', time) and np.savetxt('CH2.txt', CH2) This gives you two text files you can upload to a host like https://gist.github.com/, or included in the question if they are small enough. Then, the data can be loaded back in with np.loadtxt().

Your data is very periodic, @Saul Chang Liu. Could you supply just ONE cycle of data and we can try to fit that. Sure," the primary_frequency = the highest number in the frequency domain". However, there are clearly other frequencies on top of the primary frequency, and if we can get the data and Fourier-transform it we can include those as well for a better fit.

primary_frequency and phi_beta are fully correlated. This fit function does not make sense. The entire fit probably does not converge properly. You get error messages or warnings?

Without having the data at hand I will have to speculate a bit but from experience I would guess that you have one of the following problems
1. Misfit Model
I believe this to be the most likely. This would mean that your data just isn't a sine wave and this is in fact the best fit. Do you have any theory to suggest that your data should follow a sine wave? (Not all periodic functions are sine waves. I have seen a lot of undergrads make mistakes like this.)
2. Local Minimum
Scipy curve_fit uses the scipy.optimize.minimize function, which is a local minimizer. If your X² is non convex in parameter space you may be getting stuck in a local minimum. You can try to measure your systemic bias separately and set it as a constraint. (Or just replace C with the number you measure) Calculate the reduced Chi Squared for both and select the better seloution. Alternatively you can define your own loss functon and run a global search algorithm like scipy.optimize.dual_annealing(). (I have implemented this for distribution fitting in my fitting_toolkit repository)
3. Unstable Loss function
I do not think this is the issue. I have never had this problem with sin-wave, however I will add it for completeness. scipy.optimize.curvefit uses least squares fitting which is notoriously unstable for non polynomial models. In that case you may want to use another optimization like Maximum Likelyhood Estimation
